# A closed form of $q$-analog finite sum

Tags: q-analogs

Let $[n]:=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$. I wish to find a closed form of the following q-sum
$$I(p):=\sum\limits_{n_1+\cdots+n_p=n\atop n_1,\ldots,n_p\ge 1}\ \ \  \frac{1}{[n_1]\cdots [n_p]}=？$$
For example, we have 
$$I(2)=\frac{1}{[n]}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1+q^k}{[k]},$$
but how to obtain the general result for $p\ge 3$?

Comment: Before we begin, do you have a proof when $q \to1$?

Comment: Since for $q=1$ we have that
$$
{{p!} \over {n!}}\left[ \matrix{
  n \cr 
  p \cr}  \right] = \sum\limits_{\scriptstyle 1\, \le \,k_{\,j}  \atop 
  \scriptstyle \,k_{\,1} \, + \,k_{\,2} \, + \, \cdots \, + \,k_{\,p} \, = \,n}  {{1 \over {k_{\,1} k_{\,2}  \cdots k_{\,p} }}} 
$$
where ${ n\brack p}$ indicates the un-signed Stirling N. 1st kind, then probably your 
sum is tied to the q-analog of those numbers.